# How to add labels to land cover data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

I have downloaded Land Cover 1990 data from Digimap and clipped to a watershed I have already delineated.

My problem is that my land covers are just numbers and I cannot seem to get labels for the land covers.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  Please [edit] your question to include information about the data you've downloaded, what labels you're expecting, and a sample of your data.  What have you tried?

Comment: On the same site should be lookup table to convert codes to names